# elements are not defined at the time the script is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, attributes, prototype

I'm trying to get a data attribute of some elements, however when the object is created, the elements aren't loaded yet (which I understand). My question is what would be the best (or any) solution for this as I need to use this object in two separate functions that don't interact with each other?

```
function Data_Num_Array(){
    this.data_num_array=$("*[data-num]");
}

Data_Num_Array.prototype.get_data_num_array_element=function(string_val){
    var data_num_of_element;
    for(var i=0;i<this.data_num_array.length;i++){
        if(this.data_num_array[i].id===string_val){
            data_num_of_element=$(this.data_num_array[i]).attr("data-num");
            break;
        }
    }
    return data_num_of_element;
};

function call_me(){
    console.log(obj.get_data_num_array_element("div"));
}
```

if there's a syntax error here it's not an issue, this is just for the case of the question.

```
var obj=new Data_Num_Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(obj.get_data_num_array_element("div"));
});

$("#click").click(function(){
    console.log(obj.get_data_num_array_element("click"));
});

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div" data-num="1"></div>
        <button id="click" data-num="2"></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to JavaScript, it might be worth reading up on scoping: [MDN: Variable Scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope.)

In short, `obj` is needed across two functions, but we can leverage scoping to help us ensure that both `$(document).ready` and `$("#click")` will have access to `obj`. `obj`, on the other hand, needs to wait until the document is ready. We can hold off on instantiating `Data_Num_Array` with the `$(document).ready` callback function you're using.

With a bit of rearranging:

```
function Data_Num_Array(){
    this.data_num_array=$("*[data-num]");
}

Data_Num_Array.prototype.get_data_num_array_element=function(string_val){
    var data_num_of_element;
    for(var i=0;i<this.data_num_array.length;i++){
        if(this.data_num_array[i].id===string_val){
            data_num_of_element=$(this.data_num_array[i]).attr("data-num");
            break;
        }
    }
    return data_num_of_element;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj=new Data_Num_Array();

  console.log(obj.get_data_num_array_element("div"));

  $("#click").click(function(){
    console.log(obj.get_data_num_array_element("click"));
  });
});
```

Now, we're waiting to set up the new `Data_Num_Array` and the click event.

Also, you had a small bug in your click handler where you were calling `obj.get_data_num_array_element("button")` instead of `obj.get_data_num_array_element("click")`. (You gave you `<button>` an id of "click".)

On the more opinionated side, consider using camelCase for variable names. Less characters to type. ;)

Comment: One of the functions that need the Data_Num_Array object needs to be outside $(document).ready, as it's being called from other sources, so placing the function inside $(document).ready wouldn't work as it'd cause an error when searching for that function. I suppose I didn't explain that in my post. On your opinion, I prefer camelCase, but a colleague of mine didn't like it, so I've been attempting to write code with more underscores instead.

Comment: Is `call_me` a return-value function? If so, you'll have to wrap its actions in a `$(document).ready` and use a callback function that gets invoked when `call_me` is actually ready to return. If `call_me` isn't a return-value function, then you can still wrap it in a `$(document).ready`. `$(document).ready` can be used multiple times. Does that work?

Comment: call_me() does not have a return statement. I've tried wrapping it in the $(document).ready but then the line that calls the function returned in the console that the function doesn't exist